# After EXE installed 'No connection string named 'ConnectionString' could be found in the application config file'

Tags: winforms, entity-framework

I had winform project with Entity Framework. I have created two projects one is main and another is for Entity Framework(i.e. DAL).

It is working fine while I run from Visual Studio. Then I created Setup file of it while I installed in pc, it is successfully installed,

But when I run the program it gives an error like

> No connection string named 'ConnectionString' could be found in the application config file

Comment: Make sure web.config is copied in app folder after build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there two connection string in `web.config.` if is there remove one.

Answer (score 0):

Please check for the following at runtime:

```
string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile;
```

The program may be referring to the wrong config file name. Check the value of the above and rename the config file accordingly.